# Covariant assignment to Func requires explicit parameter

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

You can assign a method to a delegate with matching type args:

```
Func<string, DateTime> f = DateTime.Parse;
```

You can assign a lambda to a delegate with covariant type args:

```
Func<string, object> f = s => DateTime.Parse(s);
```

But you can't assign a method to a delegate with covariant type args:

```
Func<string, object> f = DateTime.Parse; //ERROR: has the wrong return type
```

Why not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Variance does not work with value types, since they need to be JITed differently.

Your lambda expression variant does not involve variance; instead, it compiles to a lambda expression with an implicit boxing conversion from `DateTime` to `object`.

If you use a method that returns a reference type, it work fine:

```
Func<string, object> f = string.Intern;
```